# Stopping a PHP based email from sending

Tags: php, forms, email, post

I'm building an email contact form that sends via the POST method using PHP. the form is at ../register.shtml, and the action redirects to ../register.php

The problem is, when register.php is opened directly (as in not via the form) a blank email sends to my inbox. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if a form was posted but also validate the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden input field in the form on your `../register.shtml` page. Then, on `register.php`, check if the hidden input value is set. If so, then process the form. If it's not set (the user didn't come from the form) then redirect back to the original page.

Here's some code:

On `../register.shtml`

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">

... your form fields

<input type="hidden" name="cameFromForm" value="Yes" />
</form>
```

Then, at the top of `../register.php`

```
if(!isset($_POST['cameFromForm'])) {
    header('location: http://www.example.com/register.shtml');
    exit();
} else {

   .... your send mail code (or whatever register.php does)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your register.php script, you should check if there is any email message in the post data, and if there is none redirect back to the form:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['message']) || $_POST['message'] == '') {
  header('Location: register.shtml');
  exit;
}

// the rest of your php code here
```

Obviously change 'message' to one of the actual fields in your form.

You might also want to check every field, or just all of the required fields. And you might want to change the redirect URL to tell the user which field they need to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is...

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  // send email logic
}
```

That way the email is only sent if something is posted to the page.

Comment: That will always evaluate to true because the `$_POST` array is always set but doesn't necessarily contain any elements.